# koltinx.parcelize.Parcelize doesn't found in kmm proyect with kotlin 1.4.20

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, kmm

I was deveoping an KMM proyect where I try to use @Parcelize annotation on my data class, and although I made all the change which suggest the oficial docuemntation of how to migrate from android.extensions to kotlin-parcelize, Android Studio still doesn't found kotlinx package.

Here is the class in my shared module where I recived the error:

[image]

Here is my build.gradle.kts of my shared module, which is the one I use @Parcelable annotation.

```
plugins {
  id("com.android.library")
  kotlin("multiplatform")
  id("kotlinx-serialization")
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods")
  id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
  id("kotlin-parcelize")
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion(Versions.compileSdk)
  buildToolsVersion(Versions.androidBuildTools)

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion(Versions.minSdk)
    targetSdkVersion(Versions.targetSdk)
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"
  }
}

// CocoaPods requires the podspec to have a version.
version = "1.0"
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.8.1")
}

kotlin {
  targets {
    val sdkName: String? = System.getenv("SDK_NAME")

    val isiOSDevice = sdkName.orEmpty().startsWith("iphoneos")
    if (isiOSDevice) {
      iosArm64("iOS")
    } else {
      iosX64("iOS")
    }

    android()
  }

  cocoapods {
    // Configure fields required by CocoaPods.
    summary = "Description for a Kotlin/Native module"
    homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"
  }

  sourceSets {
    all {
      languageSettings.apply {
        useExperimentalAnnotation("kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi")
      }
    }

    val commonMain by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
        implementation(Coroutines.Core.core)
        implementation(Ktor.Core.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Json.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Logging.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Serialization.common)
        implementation(SqlDelight.runtime)
        implementation(Serialization.runtime)
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${Versions.kotlin}")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-parcelize-runtime:${Versions.kotlin}")
      }
    }

    val commonTest by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(Ktor.Mock.jvm)
      }
    }

    val androidMain by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
        implementation(Coroutines.Core.core)
        implementation(Ktor.android)
        implementation(Ktor.Core.jvm)
        implementation(Ktor.Json.jvm)
        implementation(Ktor.Logging.jvm)
        implementation(Ktor.Logging.slf4j)
        implementation(Ktor.Mock.jvm)
        implementation(Ktor.Serialization.common)
        implementation(Serialization.runtime)
        implementation(SqlDelight.android)
      }
    }

    val androidTest by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
        implementation(Ktor.Mock.common)
      }
    }

    val iOSMain by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(Coroutines.Core.core)
        implementation(Ktor.ios)
        implementation(Ktor.Core.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Json.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Logging.common)
        implementation(Ktor.Serialization.common)
        implementation(Serialization.runtimeNative)
        implementation(SqlDelight.runtime)
        implementation(Ktor.Mock.common)
      }
    }

    val iOSTest by getting {
      dependencies {
        implementation(Ktor.Mock.native)
      }
    }
  }
}

sqldelight {
  database("PetsDatabase") {
    packageName = "com.jshvarts.kmp.db"
    sourceFolders = listOf("sqldelight")
  }
}
```

and my proyect level build.gradle.kts

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
      jcenter()
      google()
      mavenCentral()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = Versions.kotlin))
        classpath(kotlin("serialization", version = Versions.kotlin))
        classpath("com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:${Versions.sqldelight}")
        classpath("com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.28.0")
        classpath ("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:${Versions.navigation}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:${Versions.serialization}")
        classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${Versions.kotlin}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-parcelize-runtime:${Versions.kotlin}")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

plugins {
  id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "9.2.1"
  id ("com.github.ben-manes.versions") version "0.28.0"
}

apply(from = "quality/lint.gradle")
```

Finally regarding the versions which I'm using are this:

```
object Versions {
  const val navigation = "2.3.0"
  const val androidBuildTools = "29.0.2"
  const val appCompat = "1.0.2"
  const val compileSdk = 29
  const val constraintLayout = "1.1.3"
  const val coroutines = "1.4.1"
  const val kotlin = "1.4.20"
  const val ktor = "1.3.5"
  const val lifecycle = "2.2.0"
  const val material = "1.2.0-alpha05"
  const val minSdk = 26
  const val picasso = "2.71828"
  const val glide = "4.11.0"
  const val recyclerView = "1.1.0"
  const val serialization = "1.0.1"
  const val slf4j = "1.7.30"
  const val sqldelight = "1.3.0"
  const val swipeToRefreshLayout = "1.0.0"
  const val targetSdk = 29
  const val timber = "4.7.1"
}
```

Thanks you so much in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you try to add the parcelize dependency to `androidMain` instead of `commonMain`? Also why are you using Kotlin 1.4.20 instead of 1.6.10?

Comment: I added in commonMain because is where I ade use of @Parcelize annotation.  And regarding the kotlin version, because I read 1.4.20 is the version which deprecate android.extensions in favor of kotlin-parcelize. Should I upgrade to kotlin 1.6.10??

Comment: I try the solution of Emanuel Moecklin, upgrading kotlin to 1.6.0 version, and start to fail others dependecies like serialization and ktor

Comment: I wrote an article about this on medium : https://medium.com/@chrisathanas/how-to-use-parcels-on-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-kmm-e29590816624